# Accessing additional content type from a page layout (in markup)

Tags: content-type, publishing, page-layout

I have the following content types

- Testimonial Page (Inherits from Page)
- Testimonial Video (Inherits from Video)

I have a page layout that is based off of the `Testimonial Page` content type. I added a column of type `Rich Media Field` (part of the publishing features). This column has a media player. I am able to point it to a video file, which is of type `Testimonial Video`. In my page layout, I need to be able to display fields from both the `Testimonial Page` and `Testimonial Video` content type.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple inheritance isn't possible. What I would do is:
Create a new content type (Testimonial Video Page) that inherits from Testimonial Page and add the fields from the Testimonial Video. 
It's a bit more work...

Comment: This won't work for us. We're trying to keep the video separate because it will be used in other aspects of the application.

Comment: Than (in my opinion) it isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the needed fields from 1 of the 2 type to a new content type based on the other of the 2 existing types. Call it `Testimonial Page With Video`

So you'd get

- `Testimonial Page` (your existing ctype)

  - `Testimonial Page with Video` (new ctype, derived from Testimonial Page)
- `Testimonial Video` (your existing ctype)

Assign another page layout to this content type that includes the fields.

Comment: What is the 3rd bullet point? I

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to suggest here. I still don't see how it is possible.